# How to query multiples 'where' in Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-fusion-tables, intersection

I have two "where" in fusion table, so i wanted to run the code in a single where clause.

```
query: 
{
    select: 'geometry',
    from: 'tableid',
    where: "direction = 'ida'",
    where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-8.754864219111248, -63.87663083648681), 200))',
    limit: 2
}
```

I would like to run the query like this but it doesnt work

```
where: "direction = 'ida'"   AND   'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-8.754864219111248, -63.87663083648681), 200))',
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

It was the order of the query that was wrong and the +'and'+:

```
where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-8.754864219111248, -63.87663083648681), 200))' +'and'+ "'direction' = 'ida'"
```